# How to search multiple models with ransack in liquid templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, liquid, ransack

I am trying to implement ransack search for 3 models in a rails app that has liquid templates in the view. So far, I have been able to implement the search for just one model. 
In my search controller, i have;

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @courses = Course.ransack(params[:q])

    # @teachers = Teacher.ransack(params[:q])
    # @articles = Article.ransack(params[:q])    
  end
end
```

My search.html.liquid is empty since I want the search bar to show up in the navbar. So in my navbar.html.liquid, i included this;

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="{{ request.url_helpers.courses_path }}">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q[title_cont]" value=""  />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

In my routes.rb, i have

```
    resources :search, only: [:index]
```

Like I mentioned earlier, the search works for the Course model but i would like to include the Teacher and Article model as well. For the Teacher model,  i would like to search for field "firstname_cont" and "title_cont" for the Article model.

How do I combine the search for all 3 models in one search form that works well with liquid templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is pertinent to the `ransack` portion as I have no experience with liquid and it does not seem to pertain the the question at hand**

I am assuming the following

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :articles
end
```

You should be able to use a compound attribute chain like `title_or_teacher_firstname_or_articles_title_cont` e.g.

```
<form class="search" method="get" action="{{ request.url_helpers.courses_path }}">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q[title_or_teacher_firstname_or_articles_title_cont]" value=""  />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Also your controller code is traditionally represented as:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Course.ransack(params[:q])
    @courses = @q.result
  end
end
```